# public array property not populated when using method to populate

Tags: php, visibility, instance-variables

I'm making a generic function to push key-value pairs in an array that is a public property.

When I call the pushDetailsToArray function, inside the getHospitalDetails function the public property array does not seem to be populated. Although when you try to print the array inside the pushDetailsArray function, it prints. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

```
public function pushDetailsToArray($row, $array){

        foreach($row as $key => $value){

            $array[$key] = $value;

        }

                    //print_r($this->hospDetails);

        return $array;

    }

    public function getHospDetails(){

        $row = $this->queryThis( "SELECT * from tblhospitals WHERE HospID = '$this->sessionId'" );

        /*foreach($row as $key => $value){

            $this->hospDetails[$key] = $value;

        }*/

        $this->pushDetailsToArray($row, $this->hospDetails);

        print_r($this->hospDetails);


    }
```

By the way, the foreach loop that is commented out in the getHospitalDetails method works. I just want to be able to make a generic method to loop.

Comment: By the way, the foreach loop that is commented out in the getHospitalDetails method works. I just want to be able to make a generic method to loop.

Comment: Capture the return value by `$this->hospDetails = $this->pushDetailsToArray($row, $this->hospDetails)`, or make the function take `$array` by reference. Edit: also, your `pushDetailsToArray` is just `array_merge` with a different name.

Comment: I would vote for the first solution; get the function to return the value and assign this to `$this->hospDetails`. You will get VERY confused with passing by reference in php. There are some very strange special cases.

Comment: @DCoder you solved my problem instantly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why don't you just do this:

### Option 1

```
public function getHospDetails(){

    $row = $this->queryThis( "SELECT * from tblhospitals WHERE HospID = '$this->sessionId'" );

    $this->hospDetails = $row;

}
```

Unless `$row` is not an array, in which case do option 2.

### Option 2

```
public function pushDetailsToArray($row) {
    $output = array();
    foreach($row as $key => $value){
        $output[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $output;
}

public function getHospDetails() {
    $row = $this->queryThis( "SELECT * from tblhospitals WHERE HospID = '$this->sessionId'" );
    $this->hospDetails = $this->pushDetailsToArray($row);
}
```

### Another way

```
public function pushRowToHospDetails($row) {
    foreach($row as $key => $value){
        $this->hospDetails[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $this
}

public function getHospDetails() {
    $row = $this->queryThis( "SELECT * from tblhospitals WHERE HospID = '$this->sessionId'" );
    $this->pushRowToHospDetails($row);
}
```

Comment: Hi ramseykhalaf. Your option 1 is the solution indeed if it was an array only returned by row. But I would like the option to merge the row also if there is already values in hospDetails. The array_merge is the perfect solution in this case.

Comment: This is a bit of personal style thing. But as you can see option 2's pushDetails.. function doesn't touch `$this`. So I would be very tempted to change the signature to `private static` as it makes it explicit that you are not touching the current object (any dev in the future modifying the function will know he/she should not modify $this). I've met people who think this is strange, but they haven't been able to give me a good reason why.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure to user reference, you can change your `pushDetailsToArray` to :

```
 <?php
 public function pushDetailsToArray($row, &$array)
 {
     foreach($row as $key => $value)
     {
         $array[$key] = $value;
     }
 }
```

Then call it like this (phpversion >= 5.3)

```
 $this->pushDetailsToArray($row, $this->hospDetails);
```

or (phpversion < 5.3):

```
 $this->pushDetailsToArray($row, &$this->hospDetails);
```

-

```
         ********** But, I suggest not to use `reference` **************
```

You can simply change your `pushDetailsToArray` to:

```
 <?php
 public function pushDetailsToArray($row)
 {
     $array = array();
     foreach($row as $key => $value)
     {
         $array[$key] = $value;
     }
     return $array;
 }
```

then:

```
 $this->hospDetails = $this->pushDetailsToArray($row);
```

Comment: prefixing var by ampersand was never required in php5.2. you mean something like php4 ;)

Comment: @JimiDini Yes, it is never required, but from php5.3 it forbidden.

Comment: I wouldn't use this method, it's gonna cause a lot of issues unless you spend a good amount of time learning about how php does pass by reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function pushDetailsToArray($row){
        $array=array();
        foreach($row as $key => $value){

            $array[$key] = $value;

        }

        //print_r($this->hospDetails);

        return $array;

    }

    public function getHospDetails(){

        $row = $this->queryThis( "SELECT * from tblhospitals WHERE HospID = '$this->sessionId'" );

        /*foreach($row as $key => $value){

            $this->hospDetails[$key] = $value;

        }*/

         $this->hospDetails=$this->pushDetailsToArray($row);

        print_r($this->hospDetails);


    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't call my variables `$array`, it doesn't really tell you whats in them, better to give them a more semantic name, like `$output`, `$retval` or `$result`.